# How to do a scrolling repeating gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first question in stack overflow.

I am searching how to do a scrolling repeating gameObject in Unity, but I only find how doing this with backgrounds.

I got increase the size without problems, but want that the gameObject scrolling repeating when increase the size like the scrolling repeating background but in this case with the gameObject.

Any idea?

thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't undestand what you mean .. what is a `scrolling` gameObject? You mean it moves and when it gets out of the fieldofView a new one should be attached next to it?

Comment: @derHugo yes!, sorry for don't explain good.